# How to exclude specific rows in CSV using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
NO   ID     TOTAL
1    123    1000
2    456    1500
3    123    2500
4    112    4000
```

I want to exclude the rows where ID=123 and the TOTAL>3000.

```
$File = Import-Csv 'SELL.csv'
   $File | Where-Object { $_.ID -eq "123", $_.TOTAL -lt "3000" } -Exclude |
   Export-Csv 'SELLREPORT.csv' -NoType
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the syntax all wrong. Try this one.

```
$File = Import-Csv 'SELL.csv'
$File | Where-Object { 
    ($_.ID -ne '123') -or ([int]$_.TOTAL -lt 3000)
} | Export-Csv 'SELLREPORT.csv' -NoType
```

Adding `[int]` will ensure your cells are read as integers and not strings. This will allow us to use `-ne`, Not Equal, and `-ge`, Greater than or equal to.

This won't exclude matched results, but include results that don't match.

Comment: how if I want to make it exclude matched result? @Drew

Comment: @Job This will do what you are after, there is no `-exclude` option for `Where-Object`.

Comment: It still not work for me. If I have csv data like this `NO ID TOTAL
0 123 1000
1 456 1500
2 123 2500
3 112 4000
4 123 4000
`
I can only output the file like this `NO ID TOTAL
3 112 4000
`
I got it, I have to use `or` not `and`
And the other problem is, how if my $ID is not integer, I change the $ID to "A", "B".

Comment: I am having difficulties determining your requirements based on your English. Are you expecting it to exclude results if EITHER of the conditions are met, but not both?

Comment: if both of the condition met. ID=123 and TOTAL > 3000 will exclude

Comment: I have updated the answer to suit your updated requirements